# Верна ли пунктуация в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

У Ивана, на первый взгляд (?) производившего впечатление малоэмоционального человека, ведущего скучный (?) обывательский образ жизни, на самом деле (ох, уж эти тихони!) было две сильные страсти: охота и карточная игра по-крупному.

Нужны ли запятые в тех местах, где стоит вопросительный знак? Допустима ли вставка в текст взятой в скобки фразы "ох, уж эти тихони!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Ивана, на первый взгляд производившего впечатление малоэмоционального человека, ведущего скучный, обывательский образ жизни, на самом деле (ох уж эти тихони!) было две сильные страсти: охота и карточная игра по-крупному.

На первый взгляд - необособленной обстоятельство, в данном случае не является вводным словом.

Скучный, обывательский - сближенные признаки, однородные определения.

Вставка оформлена верно, "ох уж" не разделяется запятой (устойчивое сочетание в роли частицы).

Comment: Вера, как Вы считаете, не лучше ли после слова "страсти" поставить тире, обозначив таким способом приложения?

Comment: Виктор, я думаю, что двоеточие здесь более уместно. Замена двоеточия тире должна иметь обоснование, так как тире меняет интонационную структуру предложения и смысловую нагруженность ряда. В случае двоеточия делается предупредительная пауза, ряд становится смысловым центром высказывания. В случае тире паузы практически нет, а ряд имеет присоединительный характер. В нашем случае в распространенном предложении  пауза очень уместна, она в большом  объеме информации позволяет выделить ключевые слова, входящие в ряд.

Comment: Спасибо,  V e r a !

Comment: Двоеточие подразумевает вопрос "а именно?", поэтому точнее будет выбрать двоеточие.